# PowerShell script in SharePoint 2010 works via Management Shell but it doesn't work via C# code. What are possible reasons?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell

I'm trying to get some logs from the SP folder and to write them into another folder on the same machine.

So this script works via management shell but if I try to run the same operation on the sharepoint portal's page with most powerfull rights doing it in my code like this:

```
using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token);
                   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
                    delegate()
                    {
                          //PowerShell runs here
                    }
            }
```

and it doesn't work.

In SharePoint I have rights as Farm Admin.
Maybe PowerShell needs some services I have to switch on in CA or what it could be, then?

Comment: Additional info from logs. It says: "You need to have Machine administrator priviliges to run this cmdlet."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you execute this code in sharepoint, sharepoint will use the application pool account to execute it and that account must not have all rights.

Please check that at first. If it doesn't help, you maybe have to add the application pool account as shell admin:

```
Add-SPShellAdmin -username apppoolaccount
```

if that also doesn't help, try to disable UAC.

Comment: Yes it is a good decision, but the requirements for app pool account -it has to be with restricted rights. So, could I run my powershell script in sharepoint not via app poool account but as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM in the same way?